# Using InternetExplorer.Application to get a session cookie

Tags: javascript, automation

Assuming I've used InternetExplorer.Application to pro grammatically navigate to a website that in turn has set a session cookie, how can I access the value of that cookie (that is only in memory at this point)?

The only way I can think of would involve adding some client side scripting to the Document.Body.InnerHTML and then call that scripting with .Navigate("javascript:functionName()"). Assuming that function would in turn create an element with the value of the cookie in question that I could retrieve at that point.

However, this seems convoluted and I've not yet been successful. Please tell me there's a simpler way.

EDIT: My question was answered in another forum by Rick Strahl. Apparently I didn't read the documentation close enough because there is a document.cookie property that will give me the answer without any convoluted process.

Now, do I down vote my own question? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For completeness sake, I'm putting my answer that I added in the question above as the answer here.

The answer is simple, there is a document.cookie property that will give the value I was looking for. The difficulty, I found, is in finding the official documentation for the DOM accessible via the InternetExplorer.Application object. Intellisense in Visual Studio wasn't showing this property (at least for me) so I assumed there wasn't one.

I think I found the official document for the DOM here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535862(v=VS.85).aspx

and the cookie property specifically here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533693(v=vs.85).aspx

Hope this helps someone avoid chasing their tail in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to brettbaggott for pointing me at the right direction. Here is the code for those who are interested:

```
Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" _
    (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Private Function getCookie()
    Dim myIe As Object
    Set myIe = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    myIe.Visible = False
    myIe.Navigate "http://someurl"
    Do While myIe.Busy
        Sleep 20
    Loop
    getCookie= myIe.Document.cookie
End Function
```